# Find when user online in Hangout/gtalk with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-talk, google-hangouts

I need to find when my gmail contact (specified or any contact) login to Hangout/gtalk. I'm trying to do this using [google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). I looked google apps script to find-out way to do this. but unable to find.

What i'm trying to do is, when my gmail contact (specified or any contact) login to Hangout/gtalk, identified that contact is online and make some google spreadsheet entry.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (and let's hope it will never be:-)  to  get that information using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Serge is right that can't be done from gas. Its possible in other ways like appengine with xmpp but will need a perpetual backend instance constantly checking status plus the contacts need to add a special chat user (your appengine). This only covers chat not hangout.